# change the errors of my login script

Tags: php, mysql, database, validation, authentication

This is a part of my login script. I'm trying to get an error more Specifically so that if you are logging in and you type your username correct but your password is incorrect that the error is: Wrong password and not: username or password are incorrect. And if you type an incorrect username but a correct password that the error will be: wrong username.

I am not entirely sure that I am clear, if you don't understand me, I will describe my question again! :)

this is my script:

```
<?php
include('config.php');
if(isset($_SESSION['username']))
{
echo '<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0.1; URL=http://web-    stars.nl/logout.php">';

 ?>
    <div class="col-md-3">
    <?php
    }
    else
    {
$ousername = '';
if(isset($_POST['username'], $_POST['password']))
{
    if(get_magic_quotes_gpc())
    {
        $ousername = stripslashes($_POST['username']);
        $username = mysql_real_escape_string(stripslashes($_POST        ['username']));
        $password = stripslashes($_POST['password']);
    }
    else
    {
        $username = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST     ['username']);
        $password = $_POST['password'];
    }
    $req = mysql_query('select password,id from users where         username="'.$username.'"');
    $dn = mysql_fetch_array($req);
    if($dn['password']==sha1($password) and mysql_num_rows($req)>0)
    {
        $form = false;
        $_SESSION['username'] = $_POST['username'];
        $_SESSION['userid'] = $dn['id'];
        if(isset($_POST['memorize']) and $_POST['memorize']     =='yes')
        {
            $one_year = time()+(60*60*24*365);
            setcookie('username', $_POST['username'],       $one_year);
            setcookie('password', sha1($password),              $one_year);
        }
    ?>
    <?php
    }
    else
    {
        $form = true;
        $message = 'The username or password you entered are not good.';
    }
}
else
{
    $form = true;
}
if($form)
{
?>
<?php
$nb_new_pm = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query('select count(*) as nb_new_pm from     pm where ((user1="'.$_SESSION['userid'].'" and user1read="no") or     (user2="'.$_SESSION['userid'].'" and user2read="no")) and id2="1"'));
$nb_new_pm = $nb_new_pm['nb_new_pm'];
 ?>
    <div class="col-md-3">
<?php
if(isset($message))
{
}
?>
```

Comment: Just a warning, generally it is considered less secure to give a specific message about which field is wrong, because it allows an attacker to more easily discover account names.

Comment: You are writing PHP code as if this was the dark ages. You should **NOT** get checking for magic_quotes, and you should NOT be using mysql_*() functions anymore. they're deprecrated and obsolete, and magic_quotes was eliminated as well. supporting php versions old enough to have m_q enabled is just plain bad - those versions should have been tortured to death and cremated long ago.

Comment: I'll set a filter that if you typ 3 times the username or password wrong, you have to wait a day or something (don't kno exactly what I am gonna do) But thanks for warning

Comment: Yeah that's right I have to change it!! Someone is helping mee with changing it to the newest version of php next weekend.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could check if a row has been found after selecting the user with that username. If there is no row then the username is incorrect if there is a row but the password did not match the password is incorrect

After your query do something like this.

Put it after `if(isset($_POST['username'], $_POST['password'])){`

```
if(get_magic_quotes_gpc())
{
    $ousername = stripslashes($_POST['username']);
    $username = mysql_real_escape_string(stripslashes($_POST        ['username']));
    $password = stripslashes($_POST['password']);
}
else
{
    $username = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST     ['username']);
    $password = $_POST['password'];
}

$req = mysql_query('select password,id from users where         username="'.$username.'"');
// Get number of rows found
$rowCount = mysql_num_rows($req); 

if ($rowCount > 0) 
{
    // check if password has been entered correctly else give message
    // fetch your array inside this if statement
    $dn = mysql_fetch_array($req);

    if($dn['password']==sha1($password) and mysql_num_rows($req)>0) 
    {
        $form = false;
        $_SESSION['username'] = $_POST['username'];
        $_SESSION['userid'] = $dn['id'];

        if(isset($_POST['memorize']) and $_POST['memorize'] =='yes') {
            $one_year = time()+(60*60*24*365);
            setcookie('username', $_POST['username'], $one_year);
            setcookie('password', sha1($password),$one_year);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        $form = true;
        $message = 'The password you entered is not correct.';
    }
} 
else 
{
    // username is incorrect
}
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/79554/discussion-on-answer-by-szenis-change-the-errors-of-my-login-script).